# How can I draw a log-normalized imshow plot with a colorbar representing raw the raw data

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, imshow, normalize

I'm using matplotlib to plot log-normalized images but I would like the original raw image data to be represented in the colorbar rather than the [0-1] interval.  I get the feeling there's a more matplotlib'y way of doing this by using some sort of normalization object and not transforming the data beforehand... in any case, there could be negative values in the raw image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def log_transform(im):
    '''returns log(image) scaled to the interval [0,1]'''
    try:
        (min, max) = (im[im > 0].min(), im.max())
        if (max > min) and (max > 0):
            return (np.log(im.clip(min, max)) - np.log(min)) / (np.log(max) - np.log(min))
    except:
        pass
    return im

a = np.ones((100,100))
for i in range(100): a[i] = i
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
res = ax.imshow(log_transform(a))
# the colorbar drawn shows [0-1], but I want to see [0-99]
cb = f.colorbar(res)
```

I've tried using cb.set_array, but that didn't appear to do anything, and cb.set_clim, but that rescales the colors completely.

Comment: So apparently I can pass a normalization instance into imshow and the image will be normalized for me:

res = ax.imshow(im, norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm())

Still, if I attach a colorbar, the values are set to the normalized vals rather than the raw data.

Answer (score 75):

Yes, there is! Use `LogNorm`. Here is a code excerpt from a utility that I wrote to display confusion matrices on a log scale.

```py
from pylab import figure, cm
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

# C = some matrix
f = figure(figsize=(6.2, 5.6))
ax = f.add_axes([0.17, 0.02, 0.72, 0.79])
axcolor = f.add_axes([0.90, 0.02, 0.03, 0.79])

im = ax.matshow(C, cmap=cm.gray_r, norm=LogNorm(vmin=0.01, vmax=1))

t = [0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
f.colorbar(im, cax=axcolor, ticks=t, format="$%.2f$")

f.show()
```

Comment: Great answer! But why did you include the $ symbols in the format on the second-to-last line? If you leave them out, the axes labels will be in a san-serif font and match the rest of the axes labels.

Comment: Good point; I probably just copied and pasted it from existing code. I like to LaTeXize my plot text.

Comment: Still a good answer! These days also `SymLogNorm` exists. It makes a symmetric logaritmic scale centered around zero which might be better depending on your data: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm.html

Comment: The comment by Laender Moesinger (above this one) should be the answer. It works with negative values and even zero!

Answer (score 8):

If you just want the image to be log-normalized (to enhance details), but not the data (to preserve physical values), then you have to apply the transformation on the colormap itself. You can do that with the function cmap_map() given in the cookbook:
https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_ColormapTransformations.html